# AEM: Changed url for servlets

Tags: java, servlets, aem

For example:

I have Program component. And for get information - i use next url for servlet

```
/bin/dem/services/programs.json?programId=012345
```

and i added this url(`/bin/dem/services/programs.json`) to `Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler`

Now i must be changed to a Sling selector so that the pages can be cached by the dispatcher. The servlet will now be called in the following way:

```
/bin/dem/services/programId=012345.programs.json
```

Should I change something in `Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler`?
Or add changes for:

```
@Properties(value = {
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = {"GET"}),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = {"/bin/dem/services/programs.json"})
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

selectors can not be used that way. selectors are useful for **predefined** values. e.g. the following-

```
/bin/dem/services/programs.012345.json
```

also its not possible to cache requests with query string.

Comment: thanks for answer, so ...it is not suitable for dynamic information? And if i want to use it - i should add url for each id?

Comment: Yes. you can add url for each id and they would be cache-able. I wouldn't recommend it though. you may want to let the app server handle each request (instead of caching response) unless it takes a lot of resources or time for the app server to return a response.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handover the necessary information is to use a url suffix. In your case it would be

```
/bin/dem/services/programs.json/012345
```

Inside the servlet you get the suffix string from your request path info with `request.getRequestPathInfo().getSuffix()`

Another approach would be using RESTful URLs. In your case a RESTful URL would look like `/content/path/to/current/page.program.json/012345`

As mentioned before use the `@SlingServlet` annotation. Information about how to use it and which properties are availabel you can finde on https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html.

In your case the annotation would be looking like

```
@SlingServlet(
    resourceTypes = { "sling/servlet/default" }, 
    methods = { "GET" }, 
    selectors = { "program" }, 
    extensions = { "json" }
)
```

Than extend your servlet from `SlingSafeMethodsServlet` if you have only reading request (e.g. GET, HEAD, OPTION) or `SlingAllMethodsServlet` for request changing or adding data (e.g. POST, PUT, DELETE).

For CQ5 and AEM6 I suggest RESTful servlets in general because CQ5/AEM6 uses Sling which is a pure RESTful framework. In Sling it's also possible to register a servlet by resource type. You can have a look on https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/platform/sling-cheatsheet.html for how Sling works.

Answer (score 0):

Selectors can be used for arbitrary values, you just need to be careful.

you can just define a convention, the url can include 2 selectors, the first one is fixed and is used for the right servlet to be selected and the second be your variable.

for example

http://localhost:4502/content/path/to/node.selector.123.json

being 'selector' a fixed value (which is configured in your servlet) and '123' a dynamic value

if your path is fixed to /bin, then it is simpler.

What you need to be careful about is caching, the adobe dispatcher will cache each request with a different url, which means you can accumulate a lot of documents if you are not careful.

Comment: Thanks, and if I have 2 variables option? Can i use /bin/dem/services/programs.programId.012345.secondOption.543210.json ?

Comment: yes, you can, just define a convention for the order or the selectors and stick with it. one you are processing them you can only identify them by the order.

Comment: Please, Could i ask one more question.
How then need to declare a url in Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler and in @Properties(value = {
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = {"GET"}),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = {"/bin/dem/services/programs.json"})
})

Comment: First, I suggest you use the @SlingServlet annotation, which makes things easier.
Now, if you are using /bin, just remove the extension from the path ('/bin/dem/services/programs'),

Comment: @santiagozky Hi I've never seen dynamic selectors values in a slingservlet. could you elaborate more on how it would work? how sling engine would know which part is dynamic, maybe you can refer me to a code sample on git or somewhere else. thanks.

Comment: @awadheshv basically, if you have a servlet that is configured to respond to 1 selector, you can make requests that include that selector, you can add as many extra selectors as you want in the request. Sling still only needs to match one.

Comment: well, I tried this and it does not seem to work. got an error `Invalid recursion selector value 'abc'`

Comment: @santiagozky Please could you provide information on where you found such a method?